# Offline Execution of StableDiffusionPipeline from_single_file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, offline, stable-diffusion

I’m working with a Python script that uses the `StableDiffusionPipeline` from the diffusers module. Here’s the relevant part of my code:

```
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
MODEL_PATH = '/home/mypath/Stable-diffusion/limitlessvision_v20.safetensors'
pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_single_file(MODEL_PATH)
```

The line `pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_single_file(MODEL_PATH)` only works when I have an active internet connection. If I’m offline, I encounter the following error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /CompVis/stable-diffusion/main/configs/stable-diffusion/v1-inference.yaml (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27f1dc4b50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

Given that my `.safetensors` model file is already stored locally on my computer, I would like my code to function even when I’m offline.
How can I achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing and stepped through the code a bit, which is actually less daunting that it seemed initially. Here is what I found:

## Direct Answer to Question

You are missing the config file which is specified with the `original_config_file` parameter. That is why it is trying to download the file.

Some of the basic stable diffusion ones can be found here: https://github.com/Stability-AI/stablediffusion/tree/main/configs/stable-diffusion

But also the error should tell you the full path it's going to, so you can just download exactly the needed file.

I also recommend setting `local_files_only=True` just for good measure.

## Additional Data

Once you have this running you mayfind you are missing two more items (this depends on your model, and the errors will give you details.)

You need to create a directory called `openai/clip-vit-large-patch14` relative to your execution directory and download into it the contents of this: https://huggingface.co/openai/clip-vit-large-patch14/tree/main

Then by default it tries to download the safety checker model. You can similarly download it into the `CompVis/stable-diffusion-checker-safety-checker` directory, relative to your execution directory. You can get the files from here: https://huggingface.co/CompVis/stable-diffusion-safety-checker/tree/main

Or you can just set `load_safety_checker=False`, although this is not recommended.

## Sample loading code

```py
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_single_file(
   "./path/to/model",
   local_files_only=True
   original_config_file="./path/to/v1-inference.yaml"
   # load_safety_checker=False
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I made an attempt  to use the `v2-inference.yaml` file, but an issue was encountered. The error message is, `ValueError: Trying to set a tensor of shape torch.Size([320, 320, 1, 1]) in "weight" (which has shape torch.Size([320, 320]))`, suggests there might be a mismatch in the dimensions.

Regarding the use of the model `limitlessvision_v20.safetensors`, which is available for download on civitai.com, could more details about the specific steps taken be provided? This will help me to understand how to fill that .yaml file

Comment: That most likely means you have the wrong version for your model, as the size of the vectors are different than configured in the yaml file. You could try `v1-inference.yaml`. But if that does not work check if the original the error message says what specific file it's looking for? Since you are not using plain stable-diffusion it may require a specific file.

Comment: This goes beyond my experience in that matter so far, but it is actually possible that you may also have to use the `DiffusionPipline.from_pretrained` method to load your model, since it's not a stable diffusion model. This one does not seem to require a config file of this type.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute the `StableDiffusionPipeline` from the `torchdyn` library to perform stable diffusion on a single file by following these steps:

1. First, install the necessary libraries:

```py
pip install torchdyn
pip install torchaudio  # (if audio processing is required)
```

2. Next, import the required modules and classes:

```py
import torch
from torchdyn.models import StableDiffusionPipeline
from torchvision import transforms
```

3. Load your single file data into a PyTorch tensor and apply any necessary preprocessing using `transforms` from `torchvision`. For example:

```py
file_path = 'path_to_your_single_file'
data = your_custom_data_loading_function(file_path)

# Apply preprocessing if needed
preprocess = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), your_additional_transforms])
processed_data = preprocess(data)
```

4. Once the data is preprocessed, create an instance of `StableDiffusionPipeline` and execute it with the processed data:

```py
model = StableDiffusionPipeline()
output = model(processed_data)
```

Could you adapt this code to fit your specific use case and data format?

Feel free to ask if you have any issues or need further assistance!